# how to detect surrogate pair in a php utf8 string?

Tags: php, unicode

code:

```
$string = "abc";
var_dump(json_encode($string));
```

out:

```
string(17) ""abc\ud840\udd18""
```

ways I tried:

- `preg_match_all("/\p{Cs}/",$string, $match)` not work
- use `utf8_to_unicode` function to get code point, but only one code point stand for , not two

I want to detect is there an surrogate in such string. thanks!

update:
I want a function like this

`function hasSurrogate($string){
}`

Comment: I'm not sure what your end goal is here, but if it is to fix the encoded chars, you could try and pass `JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE` as the second parameter to `json_encode()`.

Comment: what was the actual result you want?

Comment: Surrogates have codes between 0xd800 and 0xffff. If your system decode all unicodes (so e.g. UTF16 or UTF32), you will never seen such codes (they will be translated). If you see them, you have surrogates (so probably UCS2). You will have two "chars", but you can interpret them just as one codepoint.

Comment: I want to detect if a string contains surrogates，I don't know how to do this.  I am confuse with encodings